# Куда сохраняется файл?

Tags: java, android, файлы

Скажите пожалуйста куда сохраняется файл? Звучит конечно глупо, но даже поиск мне не может дать результатов, а если воспользоваться функцией чтения, то он берёт из не понятно от-куда файл, а точнее текст o_O

P.S. Если надо, то приложение запускаю на Samsung S6 Edge.

P.S.S. filename при чтении и записи один и тот же.

```
void writeFile(String filename, String text) {
    try {
        // отрываем поток для записи
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                openFileOutput(filename, MODE_PRIVATE)));
        // пишем данные
        bw.write(text);
        // закрываем поток
        bw.close();
        //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Файл записан");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

String readFile(String filename) {
    try {
        // открываем поток для чтения
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                openFileInput(filename)));
        String str = "";
        // читаем содержимое
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            return str;
            //Log.d(LOG_TAG, str);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

**UPD** :

```
static void writeFile(String filename, String text) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF8");
        out.write(text);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

String readFile(String filename) {
    try {
        // открываем поток для чтения
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream (new File(filename));
        String str = "";
        // читаем содержимое
        str = fis.toString();
        fis.close();

        return str;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Чтение :

> readFile(getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/hello.txt");

Запись :

> writeFile(getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/hello.txt","Привет :D");

Ошибка :

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: hello.txt: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

Comment: емнип в home приложения

Comment: Если не можете найти его на девайсе нерутованном, то, видимо в папку `data/data/%ПАКЕТПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ%/files`

Comment: Проста нельза открыть какой модуль и увидеть куда сохраняются файлы? Атак надо уже начинать впоминать программирование!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не забудь в манифесте прописать права для работы с внешним хранилищем.

```
    <manifest ...>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        ...
    </manifest>
```

> Каталог вашего приложения во внутренней памяти указывается с
>   использованием имени пакета приложения в определенном месте файловой
>   системы Android. Технически другое приложение может прочитать ваши
>   файлы во внутренней памяти, если вы установите для файлов режим
>   Readable (доступно для чтения). Однако для этого другому приложению
>   должны быть известны имя пакета вашего приложения и имена файлов.
>   Другие приложения не могут просматривать внутренние каталоги вашего
>   приложения и не имеют разрешений на чтение или запись, если вы
>   специально не установите для своих файлов режим Readable (доступно для
>   чтения) или Writable (доступно для записи). Следовательно, пока вы
>   будете использовать режим MODE_PRIVATE для своих файлов во внутренней
>   памяти, они будут недоступны другим приложениям.

Вот тут про хранилища все написано:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста? а как "тупо" сохранить какой нибудь текст (UTF8) в файл "внутренняя память/myfolder/hello.txt"? Не как не получается :(( Сейчас тему обновлю с новыми функциями сохранения

Comment: Права забыл указать.

Comment: Короче, я нашёл что-то, там вкратце говорится что в 6 Android'е права получаются как то по новому, но не понял как, может подскажите ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030933/android-6-0-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied

Comment: Конкретно по этому вопросу там не изменилось ничего.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот таким кодом на запись/чтение byte[]. Код немного вычистил от моего старого, так что возможно где-то ошибки.

```
public static byte[] load(Context context) {
    try {
        String path = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
        File file = new File(path);
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
        int length = (int) file.length();
        int index = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
        stream.read(bytes);            
        return bytes;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}

    return null;
}

public static void save(Context context, byte[] data) {
    try {
        String path = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
        File file = new File(path);
        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        stream.write(data);
        stream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```